# Scraping and parsing Google search results using Python

Tags: python, screen-scraping, web-scraping, google-search-api

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722876/web-mining-or-scraping-or-crawling-what-tool-library-should-i-use) on realizing a general idea to crawl and save webpages.
Part of the original question is: how to crawl and save a lot of "About" pages from the Internet.

With some further research, I got some choices to go ahead with both on scraping and parsing (listed at the bottom).

Today, I ran into another [Ruby discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539798/scraping-parsing-google-search-results-in-ruby) about how to scrape from Google search results. This provides a great alternative for my problem which will save all the effort on the crawling part.

The new **question** are: in Python, to **scrape** Google search results for a given keyword, in this case "About", and finally get the links for further parsing.
What are the best choices of methods and libraries to go ahead with? (in measure of easy-to-learn and easy-to-implement).

p.s. in [this website](http://goohackle.com/tools/google-parser/), the exactly same thing is implemented, but closed and ask for money for more results. I'd prefer to do it myself if no open-source available and learn more Python in the meanwhile.

Oh, btw, advices for parsing the links from search results would be nice, if any. Still, easy-to-learn and easy-to-implement. Just started learning Python. :P

---

**Final update**, problem solved. Code using xgoogle, please read note in the section below in order to make xgoogle working.

```
import time, random
from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError

f = open('a.txt','wb')

for i in range(0,2):
    wt = random.uniform(2, 5)
    gs = GoogleSearch("about")
    gs.results_per_page = 10
    gs.page = i
    results = gs.get_results()
    #Try not to annnoy Google, with a random short wait
    time.sleep(wt)
    print 'This is the %dth iteration and waited %f seconds' % (i, wt)
    for res in results:
        f.write(res.url.encode("utf8"))
        f.write("\n")

print "Done"
f.close()
```

---

**Note** on xgoogle (below answered by Mike Pennington):
The latest version from it's Github does not work by default already, due to changes in Google search results probably. These two replies ([a](http://www.catonmat.net/c/27124) [b](http://www.catonmat.net/c/28907)) on the home page of the tool give a solution and it is currently still working with this tweak. But maybe some other day it may stop working again due to Google's change/block.

---

Resources known so far:

- For scraping, [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) seems to be a popular choice and a webapp called [ScraperWiki](https://scraperwiki.com/) is very interesting and there is [another project](https://github.com/onyxfish/fakerwiki) extract it's library for offline/local usage. [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) was brought up quite several times in different discussions too.
- For parsing HTML, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) seems to be the one of the most
  popular choices. Of course. [lxml](http://lxml.de/index.html) too.

Comment: You're on the right track, but don't be surprised if Google blocks you or starts throwing up CAPTCHAs if you get too aggressive.

Comment: @jathanism Oh.. yeah.. right.. I've thought about that. Thanks for the tip. Hope I can get my results before caught by Google.

Comment: why don't you use Google's actual [search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html)?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, good one. Gonna look at it now.

Comment: It's printing results only from 2 pages while the search result on google shows more than thousands.
Is there anyway I can crawl all the url up to the end?

Comment: If you need to scrape in bulk, there is an open source scraping python script here: http://scraping.services/?api&chapter=Source%20Code
That's when you need ten thousands of keywords or wish to get business details/knowledge tree data.
However it's bound to a license, so costs a few dollar to use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may find [xgoogle](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/python-library-for-google-search/) useful... much of what you seem to be asking for is there...

Comment: looked into it, seems like exactly the thing I was looking for. And it is the first hit in google for "google scrape python". Only searched stackoverflow and pypi....

Answer (score 1):

There is a [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) lib for emulating browser. I used it when had a necessity to login with google email account. While it's a great tool with a great idea, it's pretty old and seems to have a lack of support nowadays (the latest version is released in 2007).
It might be useful if you want to retrieve results that require cookie-handling or authentication. Likely that `twill` is one of the best choices for that purposes.
BTW, it's based on `mechanize`.

As for parsing, you are right, `BeautifulSoup` and `Scrapy` are great. One of the cool things behind `BeautifulSoup` is that it can handle invalid HTML (unlike [Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/), for example.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this awesome urllib wrapper for web scraping https://github.com/mattseh/python-web/blob/master/web.py

Answer (score 1):

Another option to scrape Google search results using Python is the one by [ZenSERP](https://zenserp.com/).

I like the API-first approach which is easy to use and the JSON results are easily integrated into our solution.

Here is an example for a `curl` request:

```
curl "https://app.zenserp.com/api/search" -F "q=Pied Piper" -F "location=United States" -F "search_engine=google.com" -F "language=English" -H "apikey: APIKEY"
```

And the response:

```
{
  "q": "Pied Piper",
  "domain": "google.com",
  "location": "United States",
  "language": "English",
  "url": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Pied%20Piper&num=100&hl=en&gl=US&gws_rd=cr&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&uule=w+CAIQIFISCQs2MuSEtepUEUK33kOSuTsc",
  "total_results": 17100000,
  "auto_correct": "",
  "auto_correct_type": "",
  "results": []
}
```

A Python code for example:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'apikey': 'APIKEY',
}

params = (
    ('q', 'Pied Piper'),
    ('location', 'United States'),
    ('search_engine', 'google.com'),
    ('language', 'English'),
)

response = requests.get('https://app.zenserp.com/api/search', headers=headers, params=params)
```

Comment: It is paid only limited free access

Answer (score 0):

This one works good for this moment. If any search is made, the scraper keeps grabbing titles and their links traversing all next pages until there is no more next page is left or your ip address is banned. Make sure your bs4 version is >= 4.7.0 as I've used pseudo css selector within the script.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests

base = "https://www.google.de"
link = "https://www.google.de/search?q={}"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
}

def grab_content(link):
    res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for container in soup.select("[class='g'] a[href^='http'][data-ved]:has(h3)"):
        post_title = container.select_one("h3").get_text(strip=True)
        post_link = container.get('href')
        yield post_title,post_link

    next_page = soup.select_one("a[href][id='pnnext']")
    if next_page:
        next_page_link = urljoin(base,next_page.get("href"))
        yield from grab_content(next_page_link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    search_keyword = "python"
    qualified_link = link.format(search_keyword.replace(" ","+"))
    for item in grab_content(qualified_link):
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract links from multiple pages of Google Search results you can use [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/organic-results). It's a paid API with a free trial.

[Full example](https://replit.com/@serpapi/google-all-pages-serpapi)

```py
import os

# Python package: https://pypi.org/project/google-search-results
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "about",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)

pages = search.pagination()

for result in pages:
    print(f"Current page: {result['serpapi_pagination']['current']}\n")

    for organic_result in result["organic_results"]:
        print(
            f"Title: {organic_result['title']}\nLink: {organic_result['link']}\n"
        )
```

**Output**

```
Current page: 12
URL: https://fi.google.com/
URL: https://www.mayoclinic.org/about-mayo-clinic

...

Current page: 18
URL: https://igem.org/About
URL: https://www.ieee.org/
URL: https://www.cancer.org/

...
```

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using google and beautifulsoup module, install it in CMD using command given below:

> pip install google beautifulsoup4

Thereafter, run this simplified code given below

```
import webbrowser, googlesearch as gs
def direct(txt):
    print(f"sure, searching '{txt}'...")
    results=gs.search(txt,num=1,stop=1,pause=0) 
    #num, stop denotes number of search results you want

    for link in results:
        print(link)
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(link)#to open the results in browser

direct('cheap thrills on Youtube') #this will play the song on YouTube
                                    #(for this, keep num=1,stop=1)
```

Output:
[image]

TIP: Using this, you can also make a small Virtual Assistant that will open the top search result in browser for your given query(txt) in natural language.
Feel free to comment in case of difficulty while running this code:)

Answer (score -1):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

import numpy as np
count=0
query=input("query>>")
query=query.strip().split()
query="+".join(query)

html = "https://www.google.co.in/search?site=&source=hp&q="+query+"&gws_rd=ssl"
req = urllib.request.Request(html, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(req).read(),"html.parser")

#Regex
reg=re.compile(".*&sa=")

links = []
#Parsing web urls
for item in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class' : 'r'}):
    line = (reg.match(item.a['href'][7:]).group())
    links.append(line[:-4])

print(links)
```

this should be handy....for more go to - 
  **https://github.com/goyal15rajat/Crawl-google-search.git**

Answer (score -2):

Here is a Python script using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` to scrape Google results.

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# desktop user-agent
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
# mobile user-agent
MOBILE_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G930V Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36"

query = "hackernoon How To Scrape Google With Python"
query = query.replace(' ', '+')
URL = f"https://google.com/search?q={query}"

headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
resp = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

if resp.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
    results = []
    for g in soup.find_all('div', class_='r'):
        anchors = g.find_all('a')
        if anchors:
            link = anchors[0]['href']
            title = g.find('h3').text
            item = {
                "title": title,
                "link": link
            }
            results.append(item)
    print(results)
```